# Display path in a weighted graph

Tags: matlab

I have a weighted graph.I have assigned three keys to each node in the graph.I want a code that, given two unique nodes in the graph, that will display all the paths connecting the two nodes if there exists a common key . The nodes can be connected in multi hop fashion also.

```
keypool = randint(n,n,[1,10]) %key pool generation
for l = 1:n
for k = 1:3
    nodekey(l,k) = keypool(l,k);%Selects key from key pool
end;
end;
for i=1:n
fprintf('%s %d \t =  %d  %d  %d \n','key_node',i,nodekey(i,:));
end
```

This is the code i have written to generate random keys to all the nodes.  I do not know how to find the path between the two nodes only when there is a common key.       Enter the number of nodes:5

```
keypool =

 5     3     1     7     7
 3     7     8     4     3
 9     3    10     7    10
 2     5     2     7     8
 7    10     7     3     5

key_node 1   =  5  3  1 
key_node 2   =  3  7  8 
key_node 3   =  9  3  10 
key_node 4   =  2  5  2 
key_node 5   =  7  10  7
```

the value of n is the number of nodes entered by the user.the above code will generate such random keys for five nodes.  if i want to find the path between node1 and node5,assuming  possible paths are: 1->2->3->5,  1->5,  1->2->5. the path which has the common key alone should be printed. that is 1->2->3->5, 1->2->5.

```
wt=zeros(n,n);
while(1)
    i=input('enter the starting node:(0 to quit):');
    if (i==0)    
        break;
    end
    j=input('enter the destination node:');
    wt(i,j)=input('Enter the cost: '); 
end
disp('Adjacency Matrix');
for i=1:n
fprintf('           %d',i);
end
for i=1:n
fprintf('\n%d          ',i);
for j=1:n
    fprintf('%d          ',wt(i,j));
end
end
Adjacency Matrix
       1           2           3           4           5
1          0          1          1          0          0          
2          0          0          0          0          0          
3          1          0          0          1          0          
4          0          0          1          0          0          
5          0          0          0          0          0
```

this means node (1,2) (1,3) (3,4) (4,3) are connected.

The user enters connectivity in the graph.the numbers in the keypool are randomly generated. the key assigned to node1 are 5,3,1 and to node5 7,10,7. these two nodes do not have a common key.Hence this path should not be printed. if a common key exists from the source (node1) the route should be traversed to the destination(node 5)

Comment: If you _want_ code, you should write some. If you have a more specific question or if you're stuck somewhere, please show what you have done so far.

Comment: till now i formed a matrix using the weights. and from this matrix i found out the paths between the two nodes in the graph. i do not know how to find the paths only when there is a common key between two nodes.

Comment: That's a good start, you should post it (inside the question) so that those that attempt to answer your question have something to work with. Also, a comprehensive example will be very helpful to understand what you're after.

Comment: considering 4 nodes. say the topology looks like a square. node1 and node2 are connected. node 2 and node3 are connected. node4 and node 3  are connected. node1 and node4 are connected. the possible paths from node 1 to 3 are:  1->2->3 and 1->4->3. after i assign the keys if a common key exists between the nodes only the path should be printed.

Comment: Again, please edit this into the question. Also, I was thinking about a _more_ specific example, with actual keys, and a step-by-step explanation of what you want the program to do.

Comment: Few more questions: what does each value in `keypool` mean? How do you determine the connectivity between nodes? And why wouldn't the path 1->5 be printed as well? Don't 1 and 5 share the same key?

Comment: i have generated a keypool of size nXn matrix. i have assigned the first three columns in the nodekey matrix. then i have assigned each row of the nodekey matrix to a node in the graph. by comparing these rows i have to find the path between given two nodes in the graph if there is a common element in the rows.

Comment: Regarding `nodekey`, MATLAB supports vectorized operations, so you could've done `nodekey = keypool(:, 1:3)`, avoiding loops. It's faster, more elegant and much more readable. That said, you haven't answered any of the questions in my previous comment...

Comment: node1 and node5 do not share a common key. the keys for node1 is 5 3 1 but the keys for node5 are 7 10 7. the connectivity of the nodes is defined by the user. if i enter the cost value between two nodes it means those two nodes are connected.enter source: 1 enter destin:2 cost:1. this means node1 and node2 are connected with cost value 1.

Comment: Okay, so where is this part about the connectivity of nodes in the example (or the code) that you've provided? How do you represent connectivity in the code? For instance, it can be a symmetrical boolean square matrix B where element B(i, j) indicates if node _i_ and node _j_ are connected.

Comment: i have plotted the topology in a biograph. the wt matrix denotes whether the nodes are connected or not.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed your last edit (page not refreshed).

Comment: if in the adjacency matrix, the value of the element is a non zero element it means the corresponding nodes are connected.

Comment: is there a way i can send my full code to u.its a bit lengthy to edit in my question

Comment: There is no need for that, I'll just try to answer briefly and point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the problem down into two steps:

1. Determine which nodes are connected *and* share the same key.
   This information would be stored in a matrix (let's denote it by `M`), which I will refer to as the *modified adjacency matrix*.
2. Find all possible paths from one node to another based on the modified adjacency matrix.

The first part can be solved like so:

```
%// Obtain matrix 'sh' where each element at position (i, j) indicates if
%// node i and node j share a key
pairs = nchoosek(1:n, 2);                %// All possible pairs of nodes
sh = zeros(n);
for k = 1:size(pairs, 1)
    node1 = pairs(k, 1);
    node2 = pairs(k, 2);
    sh(node1, node2) = any(ismember(nodekey(node1, :), nodekey(node2, :)));
    sh(node2, node1) = sh(node1, node2); %// Matrix must be symmetrical
end

%// Obtain the modified adjacency matrix
M = sh & (wt > 0);
```

I will leave the second part to you. Finding all possible paths from node A to node B using the given (modified) adjacency matrix `M` is a well-known problem. Here's [a link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27438-find-all-the-possible-paths-between-a-start-and-an-end-node-of-a-graph) to one possible implementation of it.

Hope this helps!

**P.S:**
You can simplify the generation of `nodekey` by writing:

```
nodekey = keypool(:, 1:3);
```

MATLAB's vectorized operations can really help making the code more efficient and elegant!