# All possible path from starting node to ending node

Tags: matlab

I have a weighted graph with user defined number of nodes 'n'.I want a code that, given two unique nodes in the graph, that will display all the paths connecting the two nodes  .
[Graph Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVi2X.png)

```
wt=zeros(n,n);
while(1)
i=input('enter the starting node:(0 to quit):');
if (i==0)    
    break;
end
j=input('enter the destination node:');
wt(i,j)=input('Enter the cost: '); 
end
disp('Adjacency Matrix');
for i=1:n
fprintf('           %d',i);
end
for i=1:n
fprintf('\n%d          ',i);
for j=1:n
fprintf('%d          ',wt(i,j));
end
end
Adjacency Matrix
   1           2           3           4           5
1          0          1          1          0          0          
2          0          0          0          0          0          
3          1          0          0          1          0          
4          0          0          1          0          0          
5          0          0          0          0          0
```

the matrix wt shows the connection between any two given nodes. this means node (1,2) (1,3) (3,4) (4,3) are connected.

```
fprintf('\nEnter the source');
s=input(':');
fprintf('\nEnter the destination');
de=input(':');

for i=1:n
m=s;
if(m~=i)
   for j=i:n
    if(m~=j)
        if(M(m,j)>0)
            p(i,j)=j;
            m=j;
        end
    end
    if(p(i,j)==de)
        d(i)=1;
        break;
    end
end
if(d(i)~=1)
    for k=1:j
        p(i,k)=0;
    end
    m=s;
    for k=n : -1 : i
        if(M(m,k)>0)
            p(i,n-k+2)=k;
            m=k;
        end
        if(p(i,n-k+2)==de)
            d(i)=1;
            break;
        end
    end
end
end
end


for i=1:n
j=1;
if(d(i)==1)
    for j=1:n
        if (j==1)
            fprintf('\n path: %d',s);
            kk=s;


        elseif (p(i,j)>0)
            fprintf('->%d',p(i,j));

            plot([nodes(kk, 2) nodes(p(i,j), 2)], [nodes(kk, 3) nodes(p(i,j), 3)], 'k.--')
            kk=p(i,j);
        end
    end
end
fprintf('\t\t hopcount of path %d:  %d',i,count);
count=0;
end
```

This is the code i have written to find the possible paths from the source to destination. 'p' matrix holds the final path from the source to the destination.
OUTPUT:

```
 enter the starting node:(0 to quit):1
 enter the destination node:2
 Enter the cost: 1
 enter the starting node:(0 to quit):1
 enter the destination node:3
 Enter the cost: 1
 enter the starting node:(0 to quit):2
 enter the destination node:3
 Enter the cost: 1
 enter the starting node:(0 to quit):0

Enter the source:1

Enter the destination:3


     hopcount of path 1:  0
 path 2: 1->2->3         hopcount of path 2:  2
 path 3: 1->3        hopcount of path 3:  1??? 
 Attempt to reference field of      non-structure array.
```

if i give my input for source as 3 and destination as 1 the code does not work.

Comment: Always search before asking. This isn't an uncommon task. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27438-find-all-the-possible-paths-between-a-start-and-an-end-node-of-a-graph  and http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/313699

Comment: **Pro tip:** get more familiar with MATLAB. There are a lot of commands in its arsenal that can be applied to entire matrices at once, loops are usually not the right way to go.

Comment: @EitanT: I am new to matlab. Is there any other way i can implement this? The inputs are entered by the user dynamically.

Comment: @AnnieSharon If you're new to MATLAB, then I suggest that you introduce yourself to it by taking on a less complicated task first. There are plenty of online tutorials [here](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/launchpad.html). I also suggest that you indent your code properly so that everyone can identify nested loops with ease. By the way, why aren't you using the tool that I had suggested to you in my answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188035/display-path-in-a-weighted-graph) (the same tool that Griffin has suggest you here)?

Comment: @EitanT: in tat code they are working with the co ordinates of the nodes in a 2D graph. The code which you sent for the modified matrix works. That matrix only i have to give as input the loop to find the path.

Comment: @AnnieSharon If time allows, I'll try to provide a solution for you.

Comment: @EitanT: This code works if I give my source to be 1 and destination to be 3.But it does not work the vice versa. And while displaying the path, it is coming from path 2.

Comment: Are you allowed to cross the same node twice?  Are you allowed to cross the same edge twice?
What do you plan to use the final list of paths for?  Are you sure generating a (possibly exponential) list of all possible paths is the best approach?

Comment: @dspyz: The same node should not be visited again.I need to transmit a bit sequence along the various paths depending on the hop count.

Comment: @dspyz: I executed  the program. how to view the paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better-vectorized approach (I'm assuming you can't cross the same node twice).  You want to minimize your nested for-loops as much as possible.  Use vector-and-matrix operations wherever possible.

The idea is to build a list of all the paths and simultaneously add all possible next nodes onto each element in the list.
This function returns a Mx2 cell array where M is the longest (most nodes visited) path.
Each cell in the first column contains a matrix where every row is a distinct path of length i.  Each cell in the second column contains a column vector with the corresponding costs of each path.

```
function [paths] = allpaths(wt, startnode, endnode)
    lastpath = [startnode]; #We begin with the path containing just the startnode
    costs = [0]; #The cost of this path is zero because we haven't yet crossed any edges
    paths = {zeros(0,1),zeros(0,1)}; #The set of solution paths is empty (I'm assuming startnode!=endnode)
    N = size(wt,1); #Obtain the number of nodes in the graph
    assert(N==size(wt,2)); #Assert that the adjacency matrix is a square matrix
    for i = 2 : N
        #Creates a matrix with a row for each path and a 1 in a column where there's a possible move from the last visited node in a path to this column
        nextmove = wt(lastpath(:, i - 1), :) != 0;

        #Zero out any nodes we've already visited
        d = diag(1:size(lastpath,1));
        nrows = d * ones(size(lastpath));
        inds = sub2ind(size(nextmove), reshape(nrows,[],1), reshape(lastpath,[],1));
        nextmove(inds) = false;

        # If there are no more available moves we're done 
        if nextmove == 0
            break;
        endif

        #For each true entry in our nextmove matrix, create a new path from the old one together with the selected next move
        nextmoverow = d * nextmove;
        nextmovecol = nextmove * diag(1:N);
        rowlist = reshape(nonzeros(nextmoverow),[],1);
        collist = reshape(nonzeros(nextmovecol),[],1);
        nextpath = [lastpath(rowlist,:), collist];

        # Compute the costs of the new set of paths by adding the old ones to the cost of each newly traversed edge
        inds = sub2ind([N,N],nextpath(:, i-1),nextpath(:,i));
        costs = costs(rowlist) + wt(inds);

        # For any path finishing on the end node, add it to the return list (and it's corresponding cost)
        reachedend = nextpath(:,i) == endnode;
        paths = [paths; {nextpath(reachedend, :)},{costs(reachedend)}];

        #Then remove it from the list of paths still being explored
        lastpath = nextpath(~reachedend, :);
        costs = costs(~reachedend);

        #If there are no more paths, we're done
        if isempty(lastpath)
            break;
        endif
    endfor
endfunction


paths = allpaths(wt, startnode, endnode);
for i = 1:size(paths,1)
    mpath = paths{i,1};
    mcost = paths{i,2};
    for j = 1:length(mcost)
        p = mpath(j,:);
        first = true;
        for n = p
            if first
                first = false;
            else
                printf(' -> ');
            endif
            printf('%d', n);
        endfor
        printf('  cost: %d\n',mcost(j));
    endfor
endfor
```

EDIT: Added how to print the path

Comment: I don't know how to graphically display the paths.  You can do that however you wish.  This is just code to generate a list of all possible paths and their costs.

Comment: the matrix was not displayed. how to view the elements in the matrix?

Comment: :i dont want a graph. in this code we have to go to the workspace and view the output right? can we just print the paths in the command window itself?

Comment: Yes, just don't put a ';' after the function call and it will print out to the command window.  I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: say the paths are 1->2->3 and 1->3 these two paths should be printed in the command window as: the first path is:1->2->3 the second path is 1->3.

Comment: I edited to show how you can print out the path as you described